# How do I list all files with a specific extension in my git repository?

Tags: git

My git repository tracks many kinds of files, such as Ruby files, YAML files, and Markdown files.  I want a list of all Ruby files in my repo, but I can't use `find -type f -name '*.rb'` because I also have a build directory that is not tracked by git but contains lots of ruby files. How can I list only those `*.rb` files that are tracked by git?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
git ls-files '*.rb'
```

Comment: or just `git ls-files *.rb` .. simpler

Comment: Thank you, @PA. this usage wasn't clear from the git-ls-files man page, and I couldn't find any mention of using arguments to `git ls-files` like this on SO.

Comment: playing bat golf? remove the single quotes

Comment: @PA. - that doesn't work. Without the single quotes, the shell expands the glob pattern.

Comment: ooops, OP didn't mention the shell used. It works on windows.

Comment: @jayhendren What does it mean "expands the glob pattern"?

Comment: On UNIX/Linux, if you are in a directory with the files `foo.rb` and `bar.rb`, all important shells will expand `git ls-files *.rb` to `git ls-files bar.rb foo.rb` _before_ executing `git`. If you want to keep the shell from expanding the glob pattern, you have to quote the pattern (using single or double quotes) or escape the glob character (`git ls-files \*.rb`).

Comment: If there is not any `*.rb` file in your current directory, the behavior of `git ls-files *.rb` depends on the settings of your shell. This might be either an error (no file to match) or the shell might just pass `*.rb` to `git ls-files`. Moral of the story: Use quoting and/or escaping. Without quoting or escaping, it all just depends on circumstances.