# Give list of files in the "git status" for a particular file extension

Tags: git, git-bash

If I type git status, i get the working tree status which included the files that have been modified.

I need to filter out for some specific file extension.
Is this possible? (I'm using windows, and using the latest git version).
For more information: using git bash.

Am working on a repository with more than 300 people, when I do git status, more than 1000 files will be there every week.

What is the solution here?

Comment: Do you not create any commits? `git status` only shows changes compared to the latest commit, and only the changes you made in your own copy of the repository. The 300 other people should have their own copies of the repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can [list files per extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33221895/6309)

```
git ls-files -- \*.rb
```

Or you can [list your changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57946459/6309) (if you made any) with

```
git status -- \*.rb
# or, faster, with just the filename
git diff-index --name-only @ -- \*.rb
```